# Switch middle and secondary buttons in Windows

Tags: windows, mouse

Is there a way to switch the middle and secondary mouse buttons in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

These instructions are applicable to Windows XP, but should be almost identical for newer versions of Windows.

**To change settings using your mouse:**

> 1. Click the Start button, and then click Control Panel.
> 2. In Control Panel, make sure you are in Classic View, with all Control Panel icons showing. If not, click Switch to Classic View in
>      the left pane of Control Panel.
> 3. Click Mouse to open the Mouse Properties dialog box. Click the Buttons tab for the 
>      The following settings apply to Windows XP, but should be very similar on other versions.
>      Buttons configuration box. Select the Switch
>      primary and secondary buttons check box. Click OK.
> 4. Click OK, and then click the Close button in Control Panel.

**To change settings using your keyboard:**

> 1. Display the Start menu by pressing Ctrl+Esc (or the Windows logo key). Then open Control Panel by pressing C.
> 2. In Control Panel, make sure you are in Classic View, with all Control Panel icons showing. If not, go to the left pane of Control
>      Panel and open Switch to Classic View by pressing Tab and then Enter.
>      Press the arrow keys to move to Mouse, and then press Enter.
> 3. In the Mouse Properties dialog box, on the Buttons tab, you'll see the Buttons configuration box. Select Switch primary and secondary
>      buttons by pressing S. Then press Enter.
> 4. Close Control Panel by pressing Alt+F, C.

Source: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-xp/help/change-mouse-settings